# Creating an igraph from weighted correlation matrix csv

Tags: r, igraph

First of all, I'd like to say that **I'm completely new to R**, and I'm just trying to accomplish this one task.
So, what I'm trying to do is that I'd like to create an network diagram from a weighted matrix. I made an example:

The CSV is a simple correlation matrix that looks like this:

```
,A,B,C,D,E,F,G
A,1,0.9,0.64,0.43,0.38,0.33,0.33
B,0.9,1,0.64,0.33,0.43,0.38,0.38
C,0.64,0.64,1,0.59,0.69,0.64,0.64
D,0.43,0.33,0.59,1,0.28,0.23,0.28
E,0.38,0.43,0.69,0.28,1,0.95,0.9
F,0.33,0.38,0.64,0.23,0.95,1,0.9
G,0.33,0.38,0.64,0.28,0.9,0.9,1
```

I tried to draw the wanted result by myself and came up with this:
[image]

*To be more precise, I draw the diagram first, then, using a ruler, I took note of the distances, calculated an equation to get the weights and made the CSV table.*

The higher the value is, the closer the two points are to each other.

However, whatever I do, the best result I get is this:

[image]

And this is how I'm trying to accomplish it, using [this](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/250-correlation-network-with-igraph.html) tutorial:

First of all, I import my matrix:

`> matrix <- read.csv(file = 'test_dataset.csv')`

But after printing the matrix out with head(), this already somehow cuts the last line of the matrix:

```
> head(matrix)
  ï..    A    B    C    D    E    F    G
1   A 1.00 0.90 0.64 0.43 0.38 0.33 0.33
2   B 0.90 1.00 0.64 0.33 0.43 0.38 0.38
3   C 0.64 0.64 1.00 0.59 0.69 0.64 0.64
4   D 0.43 0.33 0.59 1.00 0.28 0.23 0.28
5   E 0.38 0.43 0.69 0.28 1.00 0.95 0.90
6   F 0.33 0.38 0.64 0.23 0.95 1.00 0.90
> dim(matrix)
[1] 7 8
```

I then proceed with removing the first column so the matrix is square again...

```
> matrix <- data.matrix(matrix)[,-1]
> head(matrix)
        A    B    C    D    E    F    G
[1,] 1.00 0.90 0.64 0.43 0.38 0.33 0.33
[2,] 0.90 1.00 0.64 0.33 0.43 0.38 0.38
[3,] 0.64 0.64 1.00 0.59 0.69 0.64 0.64
[4,] 0.43 0.33 0.59 1.00 0.28 0.23 0.28
[5,] 0.38 0.43 0.69 0.28 1.00 0.95 0.90
[6,] 0.33 0.38 0.64 0.23 0.95 1.00 0.90
> dim(matrix)
[1] 7 7
```

Then I create the graph and try to plot it:

```
> network <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(matrix, weighted=T, mode="undirected", diag=F)
> plot(network)
```

And the result above appears...

So, after spending the last few hours googling and trying way, way more things, this is the closest I've been able to get to.

So I'm asking for your help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is all fine.

`head()` just prints out the first 6 rows of a matrix or dataframe, if you want to see all of it use `print()` or just the name of the matrix variable.

`graph_from_adjacency_matrix` produces a link between two nodes if the value is non-zero. That's why you are getting every node linked to every other node.

To get what that tutorial is doing you need to add a line like

```
matrix[matrix<0.5] <- 0
```

to remove the edges for correlations below a cut off before you create the graph.

It's still not going to produce a chart like your hand drawn one (where closeness is roughly the correlation), just clump them together if they are above 0.5 correlation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Do you, however, know, how to do the thing with the closeness? Or is there any other library that can do that?Thanks!

Comment: I doubt it's generally possible to plot a correlation matrix like that in 2d. Maybe there are some packages out there that try, but I'd just be googling like you.